# passing data to view from part in eclipse 4 RCP

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

How can i pass data object to view while creating a part in eclipse 4 RCP.

i have contact detail part descriptor for contact details and new part is created each time when user clicks on the contact list. But i need to pass contact information to the view. How do i pass the contact information to the view while im creating a part.

Comment: As of now i am using part.setObject method to send the data to the view where i am using Mcontribution to fetch the object value

Comment: I use part.setObject + MContribution.getObject() too. Is it a preferable way? For windows I pass data through context.